# "System cannot find the file specified" when adding a new Azure IoT Edge module in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I've followed [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-develop-for-windows) exactly and am getting the error below:

> 1. Select File > New > Project...
> 2. In the new project window, search for IoT Edge and choose the Azure IoT Edge (Windows amd64) project. Click Next.
> 3. In the configure your new project window, rename the project and solution to something descriptive like CSharpTutorialApp. Click Create to create the project.
> 4. In the Add Module window, configure your project with the following values:
> 5. Select Add to create the module.

I get this error regardless of the combination of solution folders, module names, and any other parameters that I enter during this workflow:

> The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

The net result is that no changes are made to the solution -- no IoT Edge module project is created, no other files are altered.

I've tried running Visual Studio 2019 (16.4.3) as administrator, uninstalling and reinstalling the [Azure IoT Edge Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsc-iot.vs16iotedgetools), all without success.

What can I do to troubleshoot this further?

**Update 1: I've double-checked all documented prerequisites and still have this issue.**

- Visual Studio 2019 16.4.3, all prerequisite Visual Studio workloads installed
- .NET Core workload installed the latest -- 3.1 LTS SDK -- only. Is there a hidden dependency on a specific older .NET Core 2.x SDK somewhere? Or is the documentation for VS Code on the subject out of date? (I'm using VS but was looking everywhere to see if I had missed anything)
- Git for Windows installed (via Visual Studio Installer)
- Docker Windows Desktop installed & switched to Windows containers
- Azure IoT Edge Tools for VS 2019 installed (and uninstalled & reinstalled)
- no UNC/FQ paths in the item or project template locations:

  - *C:\Users\larsk\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates*
  - *C:\Users\larsk\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ItemTemplates*
- multiple reboots
- this is on a machine that just recently got the latest (1909) version of Win10 Pro reinstalled on it.

**Update 2: Updating to Visual Studio 2019 16.4.4 did not help either.**

Comment: Looks like you are missing some pre-requisites, i would suggest you, double check the steps and pre-requisites and try again. P.S. I tried creating the project on VS and it is working as expected. I haven't faced any issues. Please see similar issue discussed here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/40805

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I [replied to that discussion](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/40805#issuecomment-580256235). None of the ideas presented there are helping in my case.

Comment: Updating VS 2019 to 16.4.4 did not help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turned out to be running a Repair operation through the Visual Studio Installer.